# How is the access to Notes & Attachements controlled?

Tags: notes

We have a user A who has full access to Accounts object and another user B who has read-only access to Accounts object.

What will be the difference in their permissions when they want to add / read Notes and Attachments for a Client?

Answer (score 2):

The read-only user won't be able to add notes or Attachments to the Account Object, but should be able to read them. Access to them is inherited from the Account permissions.